# condition match with find and if else in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to see the files which are before 15 days modified into a directory.

if not found before 15 days, then look for 10 days before.

*My Attempt*

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_DIR1="/var/log/"
diskClean (){
FileExist=`sudo find $FILE_DIR1 -mtime +15 -type f -exec ls -la {} \;|awk '{print $9}'`

if [ -f $FileExist ]
then
   echo "these are the files before 15 days."
   ls $FileExist
else
   FILE=`sudo find $FILE_DIR1 -mtime +10 -type f -exec ls -la {} \;|awk '{print $9}'`
   echo "these are the files before 10 days." 
   ls $FILE     
fi
}
diskClean
```

Comment: Unrelated, don't use backticks for command substitution. Use `$(sudo find ...)` instead.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't make much sense. What is the point of `ls -hltr ... | awk '{print $9}'`?

Comment: @oguzismail  it will show file with date wise ascending order ,  I get issue if file does not exist then it still show cindition is true  like  ` [ -f      ]`  .  this is still true. which is wrong.  because there is no file before 15 days,

Comment: @j1-lee  sort is not required.  I just need the files before 15 days, if not  then show before 10 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileList` is a string which holds the names of all files (separated by spaces), for instance something like `/var/log/foo  /var/log/bar`. You then test in your condition whether you have one file where the name equals the value of this string. While you have a file with name "/var/log/foo", you don't have one with the name "/var/log/foo  /var/log/bar" and the condition will fail.

You could use

```
if [[ -n "$FileList" ]]
```

instead.

BTW, what is the point to first list the files with all attributes (`ls -l`), and then use awk to extract just the filename? If you are interested in the filenames only, you could either use `ls -1`, or even better omit the `-exec` clause completely; `find` will output the filenames anyway.

Comment: Thank you friend,  if [[ -n "$FileList" ]]   is the right parameter I was looking for.